# UDF bag of tuples causes error "Long cannot be cast to Tuple"

Tags: user-defined-functions, apache-pig

I have a Java UDF that takes tuples and returns a bag of tuples.  When I operate on that bag (see code below) I get the error message

> 2013-12-18 14:32:33,943 [main] ERROR
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStats - ERROR: java.lang.Long cannot
>   be cast to org.apache.pig.data.Tuple

I cannot recreate this error just by reading in data, grouping and flattening, it only happens with the bag-of-tuples returned by the UDF, even when the `DESCRIBE`-ed data looks identical to the result of group/flatten/etc.

UPDATE: Here is actual code that reproduces the error.  (A thousand thanks to anyone who takes the time to read through it.)

```
REGISTER test.jar;
A = LOAD 'test-input.txt' using PigStorage(',')
         AS (id:long, time:long, lat:double, lon:double, alt:double);
A_grouped = GROUP A BY (id);
U_out = FOREACH A_grouped
        GENERATE FLATTEN(
                test.Test(A)
        );
DESCRIBE U_out;
V = FOREACH U_out GENERATE output_tuple.id, output_tuple.time;
DESCRIBE V;
rmf test.out
STORE V INTO 'test.out' using PigStorage(',');
```

file 'test-input.txt':

```
0,1000,33,-100,5000
0,1010,33,-101,6000
0,1020,33,-102,7000
0,1030,33,-103,8000
1,1100,34,-100,15000
1,1110,34,-101,16000
1,1120,34,-102,17000
1,1130,34,-103,18000
```

The output:

```
$ pig -x local test.pig
    2013-12-18 16:47:50,467 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: /home/jsnider/pig_1387403270431.log
    2013-12-18 16:47:50,751 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to hadoop file system at: file:///
    U_out: {bag_of_tuples::output_tuple: (id: long,time: long,lat: double,lon: double,alt: double)}
    V: {id: long,time: long}
    2013-12-18 16:47:51,532 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the script: GROUP_BY
    2013-12-18 16:47:51,532 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - pig.usenewlogicalplan is set to true. New logical plan will be used.
    2013-12-18 16:47:51,907 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - (Name: V: Store(file:///home/jsnider/test.out:PigStorage(',')) - scope-32 Operator Key: scope-32)
    2013-12-18 16:47:51,929 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
    2013-12-18 16:47:51,988 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size before optimization: 1
    2013-12-18 16:47:51,988 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after optimization: 1
    2013-12-18 16:47:51,996 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.AccumulatorOptimizer - Reducer is to run in accumulative mode.
    2013-12-18 16:47:52,139 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
    2013-12-18 16:47:52,158 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig script settings are added to the job
    2013-12-18 16:47:52,199 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
    2013-12-18 16:47:54,225 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting up single store job
    2013-12-18 16:47:54,249 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - BytesPerReducer=1000000000 maxReducers=999 totalInputFileSize=164
    2013-12-18 16:47:54,249 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Neither PARALLEL nor default parallelism is set for this job. Setting number of reducers to 1
    2013-12-18 16:47:54,299 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
    2013-12-18 16:47:54,299 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission.
    2013-12-18 16:47:54,308 [Thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader - Loaded the native-hadoop library
    2013-12-18 16:47:54,601 [Thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 1
    2013-12-18 16:47:54,601 [Thread-1] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 1
    2013-12-18 16:47:54,627 [Thread-1] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy.LoadSnappy - Snappy native library is available
    2013-12-18 16:47:54,627 [Thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy.LoadSnappy - Snappy native library loaded
    2013-12-18 16:47:54,633 [Thread-1] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths (combined) to process : 1
    2013-12-18 16:47:54,801 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete
    2013-12-18 16:47:54,965 [Thread-1] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - file:/tmp/hadoop-jsnider/mapred/local/localRunner/job_local_0001.xml:a attempt to override final parameter: mapred.system.dir;  Ignoring.
    2013-12-18 16:47:54,966 [Thread-1] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - file:/tmp/hadoop-jsnider/mapred/local/localRunner/job_local_0001.xml:a attempt to override final parameter: fs.trash.interval;  Ignoring.
    2013-12-18 16:47:54,966 [Thread-1] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - file:/tmp/hadoop-jsnider/mapred/local/localRunner/job_local_0001.xml:a attempt to override final parameter: mapred.userlog.retain.hours;  Ignoring.
    2013-12-18 16:47:54,968 [Thread-1] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - file:/tmp/hadoop-jsnider/mapred/local/localRunner/job_local_0001.xml:a attempt to override final parameter: mapred.userlog.limit.kb;  Ignoring.
    2013-12-18 16:47:54,970 [Thread-1] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - file:/tmp/hadoop-jsnider/mapred/local/localRunner/job_local_0001.xml:a attempt to override final parameter: mapred.temp.dir;  Ignoring.
    2013-12-18 16:47:54,991 [Thread-2] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - Waiting for map tasks
    2013-12-18 16:47:54,994 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - Starting task: attempt_local_0001_m_000000_0
    2013-12-18 16:47:55,047 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.util.ProcessTree - setsid exited with exit code 0
    2013-12-18 16:47:55,053 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task -  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@ffeef1
    2013-12-18 16:47:55,058 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask - Processing split: Number of splits :1
    Total Length = 164
    Input split[0]:
       Length = 164
      Locations:

    -----------------------

    2013-12-18 16:47:55,068 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask - io.sort.mb = 100
    2013-12-18 16:47:55,118 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask - data buffer = 79691776/99614720
    2013-12-18 16:47:55,118 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask - record buffer = 262144/327680
    2013-12-18 16:47:55,152 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask - Starting flush of map output
    2013-12-18 16:47:55,164 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask - Finished spill 0
    2013-12-18 16:47:55,167 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task - Task:attempt_local_0001_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
    2013-12-18 16:47:55,170 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner -
    2013-12-18 16:47:55,171 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task - Task 'attempt_local_0001_m_000000_0' done.
    2013-12-18 16:47:55,171 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - Finishing task: attempt_local_0001_m_000000_0
    2013-12-18 16:47:55,172 [Thread-2] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - Map task executor complete.
    2013-12-18 16:47:55,192 [Thread-2] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task -  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@38650646
    2013-12-18 16:47:55,192 [Thread-2] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner -
    2013-12-18 16:47:55,196 [Thread-2] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger - Merging 1 sorted segments
    2013-12-18 16:47:55,201 [Thread-2] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger - Down to the last merge-pass, with 1 segments left of total size: 418 bytes
    2013-12-18 16:47:55,201 [Thread-2] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner -
    2013-12-18 16:47:55,257 [Thread-2] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local_0001
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to org.apache.pig.data.Tuple
            at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POProject.getNext(POProject.java:408)
            at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.processInput(PhysicalOperator.java:276)
            at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POProject.getNext(POProject.java:138)
            at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POProject.getNext(POProject.java:312)
            at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POForEach.processPlan(POForEach.java:360)
            at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POForEach.getNext(POForEach.java:290)
            at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigMapReduce$Reduce.runPipeline(PigMapReduce.java:434)
            at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigMapReduce$Reduce.processOnePackageOutput(PigMapReduce.java:402)
            at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigMapReduce$Reduce.reduce(PigMapReduce.java:382)
            at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigMapReduce$Reduce.reduce(PigMapReduce.java:251)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:176)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:572)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:414)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:392)
    2013-12-18 16:47:55,477 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - HadoopJobId: job_local_0001
    2013-12-18 16:47:59,995 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - job job_local_0001 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
    2013-12-18 16:48:00,008 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
    2013-12-18 16:48:00,010 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
    2013-12-18 16:48:00,011 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStats - Detected Local mode. Stats reported below may be incomplete
    2013-12-18 16:48:00,015 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStats - Script Statistics:

    HadoopVersion   PigVersion      UserId  StartedAt       FinishedAt      Features
    0.20.2-cdh3u6   0.8.1-cdh3u6    jsnider 2013-12-18 16:47:52     2013-12-18 16:48:00     GROUP_BY

    Failed!

    Failed Jobs:
    JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
    job_local_0001  A,A_grouped,U_out,V     GROUP_BY        Message: Job failed! Error - NA file:///home/jsnider/test.out,

    Input(s):
    Failed to read data from "file:///home/jsnider/test-input.txt"

    Output(s):
    Failed to produce result in "file:///home/jsnider/test.out"

    Job DAG:
    job_local_0001


    2013-12-18 16:48:00,015 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
    2013-12-18 16:48:00,040 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser - ERROR 2244: Job failed, hadoop does not return any error message
    Details at logfile: /home/jsnider/pig_1387403270431.log
```

And the three java files:

Test.java

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.pig.Accumulator;
import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.PigException;
import org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException;
import org.apache.pig.data.BagFactory;
import org.apache.pig.data.DataBag;
import org.apache.pig.data.DataType;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.schema.Schema;

public class Test extends EvalFunc<DataBag> implements Accumulator<DataBag>
{
    public static ArrayList<Point> points = null;

    public DataBag exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
            return null;
        accumulate(input);
        DataBag output = getValue();
        cleanup();
        return output;
    }

    public void accumulate(DataBag b) throws IOException {
        try {
            if (b == null)
                return;
            Iterator<Tuple> fit = b.iterator();
            while (fit.hasNext()) {
                Tuple f = fit.next();
                storePt(f);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            int errCode = 2106;
            String msg = "Error while computing in " + this.getClass().getSimpleName();
            throw new ExecException(msg, errCode, PigException.BUG, e);           
        }
    }

    public void accumulate(Tuple b) throws IOException {
        try {
            if (b == null || b.size() == 0)
                return;
            for (Object f : b.getAll()) {
                if (f instanceof Tuple) {
                    storePt((Tuple)f);
                } else if (f instanceof DataBag) {
                    accumulate((DataBag)f);
                } else {
                    throw new IOException("tuple input is not a tuple or a databag... x__x");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            int errCode = 2106;
            String msg = "Error while computing in " + this.getClass().getSimpleName();
            throw new ExecException(msg, errCode, PigException.BUG, e);           
        }
    }

    @Override
    public DataBag getValue() {

        if (points == null)
            points = new ArrayList<Point>();
        Collections.sort(points);

        DataBag myBag = BagFactory.getInstance().newDefaultBag();

        for (Point pt : points) {
            Measure sm = new Measure(pt);
            myBag.add(sm.asTuple());
        }
        return myBag;
    }

    public void cleanup() {
        points = null;
    }

    public Schema outputSchema(Schema input) {
        try {
            Schema.FieldSchema tupleFs 
                = new Schema.FieldSchema("output_tuple", Measure.smSchema(), DataType.TUPLE);
            Schema bagSchema = new Schema(tupleFs);
            Schema.FieldSchema bagFs = new Schema.FieldSchema("bag_of_tuples", bagSchema, DataType.BAG);
            return new Schema(bagFs);
        } catch (Exception e){
                return null;
        }
    }

    public static void storePt(Tuple f) {
        Object[] field = f.getAll().toArray();

        Point pt = new Point(
                field[0] == null ? 0 : (Long)field[0],
                field[1] == null ? 0 : (Long)field[1],
                field[2] == null ? 0 : (Double)field[2],
                field[3] == null ? 0 : (Double)field[3],
                field[4] == null ? Double.MIN_VALUE : (Double)field[4]
            );

        if (points == null)
            points = new ArrayList<Point>();

        points.add(pt);
    }
}
```

Point.java:

```
package test;

public class Point implements Comparable<Point> {
    long id;
    long time;
    double lat;
    double lon;
    double alt;

    public Point(Point c) {
        this.id = c.id;
        this.time = c.time;
        this.lat = c.lat;
        this.lon = c.lon;
        this.alt = c.alt;
    }

    public Point(long l, long m, double d, double e, double f) {
        id = l;
        time = m;
        lat = d;
        lon = e;
        alt = f;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Point other) {
        final int BEFORE = -1;
        final int EQUAL = 0;
        final int AFTER = 1;

        if (this == other) return EQUAL;
        if (this.id < other.id) return BEFORE;
        if (this.id > other.id) return AFTER;
        if (this.time < other.time) return BEFORE;
        if (this.time > other.time) return AFTER;
        if (this.lat > other.lat) return BEFORE;
        if (this.lat < other.lat) return AFTER;
        if (this.lon > other.lon) return BEFORE;
        if (this.lon < other.lon) return AFTER;
        if (this.alt > other.alt) return BEFORE;
        if (this.alt < other.alt) return AFTER;
        return EQUAL;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return id + " " + time; 
    }
}
```

Measure.java:

```
package test;

import org.apache.pig.data.DataType;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.data.TupleFactory;
import org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.schema.Schema;

public class Measure {
    private long id;
    private long time;
    private double lat;
    private double lon;
    private double alt;

    public Measure(Point pt) {
        id = pt.id;
        time = pt.time;
        lat = pt.lat;
        lon = pt.lon;
        alt = pt.alt;
    }

    public Tuple asTuple() {
        Tuple myTuple = TupleFactory.getInstance().newTuple();
        myTuple.append(id);
        myTuple.append(time);
        myTuple.append(lat);
        myTuple.append(lon);
        myTuple.append(alt);
        return myTuple;
    }

    public static Schema smSchema() {
        Schema tupleSchema = new Schema();
        tupleSchema.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("id", DataType.LONG));
        tupleSchema.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("time", DataType.LONG));
        tupleSchema.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("lat", DataType.DOUBLE));
        tupleSchema.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("lon", DataType.DOUBLE));
        tupleSchema.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("alt", DataType.DOUBLE));
        return tupleSchema;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your UDF?

Comment: I can't post my code easily.  I can't share the actual code for work reasons, and it's too enormous to sanitize for sharing.  What part do you expect to find the error in?  Schema, or how the output bag is built, or...?  If I don't find a solution I will write a tiny UDF to try and reproduce the error in a clean context.

Comment: Post the outputSchema method (if defined), the signature of the exec method, and how the output bag is built.

Comment: Complete code added, you can see that now (and everything else).

Comment: Does your code run if you don't `FLATTEN` and just `DUMP U_out`?

Comment: Yes.  Here's the output:
`U_out: {bag_of_tuples: {output_tuple: (id: long,time: long,lat: double,lon: double,alt: double)}}
({(0,1000,33.0,-100.0,5000.0),(0,1010,33.0,-101.0,6000.0),(0,1020,33.0,-102.0,7000.0),(0,1030,33.0,-103.0,8000.0)})
({(1,1100,34.0,-100.0,15000.0),(1,1110,34.0,-101.0,16000.0),(1,1120,34.0,-102.0,17000.0),(1,1130,34.0,-103.0,18000.0)})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to cast the return of the UDF to the appropriate bag:

```
U_out = FOREACH A_grouped
    GENERATE FLATTEN(
        (bag{tuple(long,long,double,double,double)})(test.Test(A))
    ) AS (id:long, time:long, lat:double, lon:double, alt:double);
```

Even though the schema returned by the UDF is correct, the output still needs to be cast, in order to work correctly.